# What is the image of this preposition?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Laura looked faint, and her face paled white **around** freckled, sunburned cheeks and peeling nose.

Is it more like the area of cheeks and the nose? Not like surrounding regions?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning would be [***around***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/around) sense 13:

> 13) in the vicinity of; near to   ⇒ "somewhere around the building"

So in your example:

> Laura looked faint, and her face paled white **in the area of** freckled, sunburned cheeks and peeling nose.

The surrounding regions are being described.

Answer (score 0):

- Laura looked faint, and her face paled white around freckled, sunburned cheeks and peeling nose.

In a very course/rough manner, this means

- Laura looked faint, and her **entire** face paled white; **her face had** freckled, sunburned cheeks and **a** peeling nose, but **one cannot see paleness directly on freckles, sunburned cheeks, or a peeling nose.**

It was a way of describing the sunburned aspects of her face at the same time as describing her becoming pale.  It's painting an impressionistic picture of seeing someone become pale in relationship to her freckled sunburned cheeks and a peeling nose.

Similarly, of the Cheshire Cat, one could say, "And the cat's face disappeared **around** his bright, white, glowing teeth."

Or of a mountainside: "And as the sun went down, the mountainside grew black **around** the speckles of light that came from the houses where people went about their evening business."